# validating whether the text entered in textbox is numeric

Tags: vb.net

I have a text box where user enters 'School-fees'. I need the user to enter numeric data only.Since calculation is not possible with string data. However user might enter text like '$50'.

I do not prefer Using MASKED_text_box as it shows '***_*_**' inside text box.
What can I do ? Please help.

Comment: you want allow `$` and numeric olny ah?

Comment: no not $ also. Only numeric. If user enter $ then he should be informed.

Comment: it would be great if 'Nothing gets typed' when user enters characters other than 0-9

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
Private Sub TextBox4_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox4.KeyPress

    If (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) < 48) _
         Or (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Asc(e.KeyChar) > 57) Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What if they want to hit the backspace?

```
Private Sub tb_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles tb.KeyPress
 Select Case Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar)
  Case 48 To 57 
    'numbers are allowed
  Case Keys.Back 
    'ok to hit the back space
  Case Keys.Enter
    'handle an enter key
    e.Handled = True
  Case Else
    e.Handled = True
 End Select
End Sub
```